# What is the best way to persist data between pages within admin on rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

We have a simple CRUD admin on rest project and with one of our objects, we would like to "Save and create another" with some prefilled in form fields.  What is the best way to persist data within AOR?

Right now, I have a solution working using localStorage, but it is not awesome.  I have to refresh the 2nd form to have the data prepopulated.

We are thinking about modifying the URL params to include the prefilled form fields, but this seems like a lot of work for something that should be pretty straightforward, particularly within an admin framework.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The `Create` component accepts a `record` prop to setup initial values of the form. This values is merged with the values of the `defaultValue` prop (can be a function) and values from the `admin.record` state in redux.

So in your situation the `defaultValue` prop would allow you to generate the data from the params prop of redux router.